# blackberry phonegap app closing after giving an error of being out of memory

Tags: blackberry, cordova, blackberry-webworks

I am building a phonegap app for blackberry smartphones. im using phonegap version 1.3.0 
in my app, after my first page loads, on a bit of scrolling and exploring, i get a dialog asking me to close the open apps as memory is too low and the only app open is mine. On ignoring that after a minute another dialog comes saying sorry! the memory is too low so closing this app.

 also sometimes i get an error saying that the page is too large to load and the page (and the app) is closed.

my app consists of 6-7 pages and only a couple of pages are big and have many images (about 25). can the images be causing a problem?  in any case the data downloaded and used does not exceed 5MB.

Can anyone tell me what to do in order to remedy this?

Comment: I'm assuming that you didn't find a solution for this? I'm having similar problems. I don't even have any freaking images.

Comment: i removed all images, have a basic app now, even that crashes after sometime of use. something related to less ram but i've got no idea what to do about it

Comment: try using the newest bb sdk...

Comment: I thought so... I'm doing the same, trying to get the app to the base...

Comment: tell me if something works :)

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a known issue with webworks and certain models of Blackberry phones - See the following [thread](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/Device-memory-is-Low-issue-for-an-WebWork-app/td-p/1166441/page/16) for a discussion on this specific problem. This is an issue with Some suggestions are to move to Webworks 2.2 but even this does not fix it. (We are facing the same issues as well and hopefully BB fixes it soon).